# How to redirect profiles in multisite

Tags: wordpress, redirect, profile, multisite

I am crafting a multisite–  A blog.com and   B  blog.com

1. Blog.com is the site where all members of specified role have their profiles and directory.
2. Subdomain.blog.com is open for all, everyone can register and interact. I don’t want any user to edit profiles, add photos here. So this blog doesn’t have user profiles page and directories page.
3. Some handful of members of blog.com are added manually to subdomain.blog.com as members/contribtors

= How can I redirect the all user’s profile to blog.com

like this     subdomain.blog.com/user/xxxx  to blog.com/user/xxxx

Regards

Comment: If I'm right the problem you'll encounter if you do that is that users will have to relog on the main site if they're coming from the other site, as the sessions are not shared.

Comment: To see the the profiles, no relogin is requred .  Confirmed